# Unable insert data into Mysql DB in for loop using PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a forloop php mysqli script. If I have a 2 or more data. I can insert it all. BUT when I try to put a exist id script it will only insert 1 data of the 2 data. If anyone can rewrite the script that exist script will work. I'll appreciate it very much. Thank you.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){

  $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST["id"][$i]);
  $queryexist = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM profile WHERE id='".$id."'");
  if (mysqli_num_rows($queryexist) > 0){
    echo "<center><div style='background-color:#dd8383; align:center; padding:4px;'><b>ID <font size='2'>[ $id]</font> already entered!</b></div></center>";
  } else {

    $counter = count($_POST["id"]);
    for ($i=0; $i<=($counter); $i++) {
      $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST["id"][$i]);
      $ownername= mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST["ownername"][$i]);

      if(!empty($_POST["id"][$i])){

        $query = "INSERT INTO profile (objid,ownername) VALUES ('$id','$ownername')";

        $result=mysqli_query($link,$query);
      }
    }
    if($result) {
?>
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
  alert('SUCCESSFULLY SAVE');
  window.top.location.href = "index.php";
</script>
<?php
    } else { 
      die('ERROR: ' . mysqli_error($link));
    }
  }
}
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: you are using MySQLI and here this function belongs to Mysql mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: sorry sir. I miss type. I edit it already. Thank you.

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: The script is working normally. But when i set a trapping of exist script above the $counter = count($_POST["id"]); for loop. I cannot get to insert 2 entries anymore..

Comment: I think you can set your success message in PHP instead of JS. Is it? I think   Js stop the execution.

Comment: ic. but that script for me now is working ok. the real problem of this is the exist data. :( i have a hard time. if i not using the for loop. it is easy. but i am using the for loop. i can't make it work. :(. if i insert two or more data. it will insert the 1st one but 2nd data will not and the exist script will block it. which is not should be doing it. idk what to do anymore. im stuck. :( sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I'm unable to understand what you want to achieve?

Comment: i just want the exist script work with the for loop script insert.